# How to get data between start and endate and also data must be greater than 2018 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to fetch data between start and end dates and also only the data which is greater than year 2018.

**Example:**

```
if Startdate =  2016-01-01, 
   Enddate = 2018-03-01
```

I need to fetch data only from 2018-01-01 to 2018-03-01.

How to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: If you only want data between `20180101` and `20180301` which use `20160101` as the first input parameter, and not `20180101` in the first place? It's unclear what you're *really* asking here.

Comment: Start and enddates are parameters for users to select and they can select any date but i have to restrict the data to fetch only from 2018

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using @Startdate and @Enddate as parameters.

The easiest way is just include the additional criterion in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM  mytable mt
WHERE mt.startdate >= @Startdate 
      and mt.enddate <= @Enddate
      and mt.startdate  >= '20180101';
```

This is one of those queries though, that when you see it again in 6 months, you'll ask who the heck wrote that crap (before you realise it was you).

While the above is accurate, a more pleasing version (where the logic is much easier to see) is to modify the @Startdate first

```
IF @Startdate < '20180101' SET @Startdate = '20180101';

SELECT *
FROM  mytable mt
WHERE mt.startdate >= @Startdate 
      and mt.enddate <= @Enddate;
```

Comment: I shoudn't pull the date if both dates are less than 20180101. I have to pull date between start and enddates and make sure that fetched data is only greater than 20180101. Also I have 2 datefileds in query like Startdate=@Startdate and Enddate=@enddate

Comment: You can modify the field names easily but I've edited it anyway. Regarding not pulling the data - it won't in either situation. In the second one, for example, say you passed startdate = '20100101' and enddate = '20101231'. The IF statement changes the startdate to '20180101' so the query tries to find all rows with startdate after 1/1/2018 and with an enddate before 31/12/2010 - which is obviously no rows.

Comment: I actuallt tried ur 1st suggestion yesterday itself and it didn't fetched data when i gave startdate less than 20180101 and enddate greater than 20180101 like in my example. I will try ur 2nd suggestion and let u know if that solves the issue or not. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? [Here is a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=092283ce705705e9d9615a8a863c104e) with example data and results - they both work as expected as far as I can see. If not, please edit the fiddle (and post the new link) showing which combinations don't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, if @startDate and @endDate are parameters. You have to add a AND in order to check if startDate is greater than your base date (2018)

you can also replace the '2018-01-01' with an @baseDate parameter

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE      
    yourTable.startDate > @startDate
    AND yourTable.startDate > '2018-01-01'
    AND yourTable.endDate < @endDate
```

Comment: I think i have to be bit more clear, there are 2 different date fileds. table.startdate=@startdate and table.Enddate=@enddate this is my curent query will be